# python socket in android fails to connect to python server run in virtualbox

Tags: python, android, sockets, virtualbox

I connected both my android phone and computer where a python server runs in a virtual box to the same Wifi. I can connect a client to a server in the same VirtualBox, but doesn't work from a phone. I have limited knowledge of networking. I suppose the IP address from server and client is the same and it should work. Could anyone give me some hints why it doesn't connect and maybe how to debug it please?

I type hostname -I in the terminal in my VirtualBox Ubuntu
and get

```
10.0.2.15.
```

I've added this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

python server code

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port = 10050
socket_address = ('10.0.2.15',port)
server_socket.bind(socket_address)
server_socket.listen(5)
client_socket,addr = server_socket.accept()
```

android python client code (I use chaquo.python.android to run python script on android)

```
def connect():
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host_ip = '10.0.2.15'
    port = 10050 
    client_socket.connect((host_ip,port))
```

the error on android

```
Process: com.example.simplecamera, PID: 17958
com.chaquo.python.PyException: TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code of python server is exact same as you are executing than the I would suggest you to change

```
client_socket,addr = server_socket.accept()
```

to

```
while True:
    client_socket,addr =server_socket.accept()
    print('[+] connection from>>',addr)
```

The server will be needed to run continuously to connect and accept

so the program will look like

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port = 10050
socket_address = ('10.0.2.15',port)
server_socket.bind(socket_address)
server_socket.listen(5)
while True:
    client_socket,addr =server_socket.accept()
    print('[+] connection from>>',addr)
    #to close connection
    client_socket.close()
```

And have a look at https://github.com/dntfury/scaling-winner/blob/master/server_client_part_2/Server.py for exact similar server

Comment: Thanks first. But server_socket.accept() is blocking to get connection from the client, isn't it? And in addition my client and server work successfully when they run on the same Virtualbox.

Comment: The above program was a simple version but work correctly. Threads can be used to improve it or make changes for making it non-blocking.  Also The client and server will work ok when are on same machine, but you need to give the IP as '0.0.0.0' to be able to connect the different devices from the same network.

Comment: I just tried ip 0.0.0.0 and your code but still doesn't work. By the way why 0.0.0.0 would work? I mean the fact it's blocking is fine as it waits for the client to connect to. The problem is the client on another device can't recognize that ip to connect to the server...right?

Comment: I think the problem is to do with the server running in VirtualBox but I don't know why yet. I can do it successfully on my host computer and phone now.